# How long can I keep espresso in the fridge?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, coffee, espresso

I often make espresso with a bialetti moka. I made some espresso martinis for my family at a party earlier this year and I have been asked for some more over Christmas.

How long can I keep espresso coffee made with a bialetti in the fridge? If it can be stored for a long time, can I top it up with more coffee as I make it, or should each batch be stored separately?

Comment: @sourd'oh Ah, I didn't find it as I was searching based on 'espresso' rather than 'coffee'. It's mostly a dupe, but the topping up aspect is fresh. I've raised in chat.

Comment: I don't know that topping up would significantly change the answer though. As SAJ points out, at the end of a week, even though some shots may only be a day old, there is still week old coffee in there.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you were making an espresso based alcoholic beverage I'd recommend infusing the beans in the liquor for at least several weeks instead of brewing the coffee. It'll likely taste "fresher".

Comment: @JasonTrue Good idea. I think making either a coffee tincture or a syrup with coffee & sugar would have a much better shelf life than just storing the coffee.

Comment: I suggest keeping this question separate/open. Espresso has some distinct culinary uses apart from "drinking coffee." I found it useful as a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How long is it safe to drink coffee after brewed?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/how-long-is-it-safe-to-drink-coffee-after-brewed) which indicates between 4-7 days is reasonable.

You do *not* want to continually top off old coffee with new.  While I cannot imagine that would give you good tasting results, it would also let any pathogens which do take hold continue essentially forever without being thrown away.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure how long you can keep it in the refrigerator, but it should be essentially indefinite in the freezer. You could freeze it in ice cube trays, then when the cubes are set, transfer them to a plastic bag for easy storage and access. You could even make each cube the right amount for a single drink.